# I'm planning a roadtrip to the moon. What is going to be my best transfer orbit? How far will it be?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, crewed-spaceflight, orbital-maneuver, trajectory, hohmann-transfer

Fed up with clouds ruining clear nights here on earth, I point my car upwards, and head for the moon. My car can provide the same amount of relative thrust it can going 65 mph, simply in whatever direction I choose. I can burn continuously at this rate. This is going to take awhile. Thankfully, I brought plenty of snacks and gas, so fuel is not a concern.

Hoping to get there as fast as humanly possible, without ignoring gravity, what is going to be my best lunar transfer orbit? Will a Hohmann serve best, or will my low thrust mean another orbit will be better? What is my Odometer going to show upon arrival?

Edit 1: The car begins in low earth orbit. Very low earth orbit, simply ignoring the atmosphere, so distance doesn't change, but escaping the earth and entering an initial orbit is no longer an issue.

Comment: Well, to start with, I'm tolerably certain your car does not have enough thrust-to-weight to enter orbit at all. If you actually start in LEO, a "low-thrust spiral" is the likely orbit.

Comment: @NathanTuggy That is an extremely good point. Escape velocity is going to be a challenge for a 10 year old Subaru. I'll add the assumption of a LEO.

Comment: Your formulation is going to invite an awful lot of Technically Correct (The Best Kind of Correct) responses. I strongly recommend you ditch the Subaru and say what you really mean.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: If we assume the 65mph is in *any* direction, including *up*, that's still going to work. Instead of escape velocity, you just point your car straight up and start going at such a moment that in 154 days (Moon's orbital radius / 65 mph) it's directly above your starting point.

Comment: As poorly worded as the problem statement is, it does specify *thrust* rather than *speed*.

Comment: Naturally, you drive a Mercury or a Saturn, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Car accelerations vary a lot, but from [this table](http://www.zeroto60times.com/vehicle-make/toyota-0-60-mph-times/), 3 m/s² seems like a safe bet.

The Hohmann transfer burn towards the Moon from LEO is around 3100 m/s, so the "burn" is only going to take about 17 minutes. That is quick enough for a transfer orbit burn, so a low acceleration spiral is not required.

As for the odometer, that is going to display half the perimeter of the transfer ellipse, that is around 400000 km depending on where in its orbit the Moon is.

Comment: 0-60 mph in 8 seconds is about 3.3 m/s^2, not 10 m/s^2 (which is about 1g).

Comment: @RussellBorogove Where have I left my head? :)